# How can I access to the 'Choice' options? - PDFTK/mikehaertl/PHP/LINUX

Tags: php, linux, pdftk, php-pdftk

Recently I started work with pdftk, all good, but i can't access to all '**FieldType: Choice**' (is like a dropdown or a html select tag), Options!, somebody could help me?

my code is:

```
 $pdf = new mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf('./files/forms/uploads/imported.pdf');
 $results = $pdf->getDataFields();
echo '<pre>';
echo print_r($results);
```

[image]

then o can't find a solution to be able to access to the dropdown list options :

[image]

Comment: Could you post the output of `pdftk ./files/forms/uploads/imported.pdf dump_data_fields_utf8` ? This would make it clear whether the problem is on the pdftk side or on the php-pdftk side.

Comment: Yes, look this, I attached the command line photo and the results, as you can look the FieldType: Button shows well the Opts, but the FieldType: Choice no... @notautogenerated

Comment: It seems the issue lies with pdftk and not php-pdftk. Which version of pdftk are you using? By the way, you should probablly edit your question instead of posting an answer (and text is easier to work with than screenshots).

Comment: what should I do?, uninstall and re-install pdftk by commandline? the pdftk version is  0.10.3 , I installed it via composer @notautogenerated

Comment: php-pdftk version 0.10.3 is fine, no need to reinstall it. You can find your version of pdftk (as opposed to php-pdftk) with `pdftk --version`. If that reads 2.02 or lower, then I would suggest you to uninstall pdftk and replace it by its successor pdftk-java (from e.g. homebrew if you are on Mac, or your package manager if you are on Linux), which fixes a few bugs like yours. Full disclosure: I maintain pdftk-java.

Comment: yes, you're rigth my pdftk version is 2.02... then how can install pdftk-java on Ubuntu server?, there are repos for that? or via apt?

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.10 or newer, `apt install pdftk-java` will do. Otherwise download the package from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/hirsute/+source/pdftk-java and install it manually with dpkg.

Comment: Thank you so much!, I done!, now all working ok! :D @notautogenerated